# Programmatically modifying a specific line in a text file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Help with what I suspect to be pretty simple would be much appreciated.

I want to be able to programmatically change a certain line in a configuration file.  Specifically, the file looks like

```
...Other lines...
# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=test.db
...Other lines...
```

I want to be able to replace "test.db" with "production.db", etc. Other programs may add or delete lines, so I can't count on a consistent line number, but there is no other line containing "dbms.active_database="

How might I best do this?

Thank you.

Comment: what programming language do you want to use to edit it? using python would be fast and simple

Comment: Python would be okay, but being able to do it from via shell programming (sed or awk??) would be even better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\(^dbms\.active_database=\)test\.db/\1production.db/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v name0fNewDb="HEythere.db"  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}/dbms.active_database/{$2=name0fNewDb}1'
...Other lines...
# The name of the database to mount
dbms.active_database=HEythere.db
...Other lines...
```

If I understood problem statement right, this should help you in doing the changes only on the line which consist of `"dbms.active_database"`. Where it will replace the right part of `=` . `name0fNewDb` is a variable to which you can assign any text of your requirement.